# How to get Range object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-11

I want equivalent code of

```
var nbLineStart=textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length - 1;
            var nbLineEnd=textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionEnd).split("\n").length - 1;
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
                try{
                    range.moveToElementText( textarea );
                }catch(e){}
                range.setEndPoint( 'EndToStart', range );
                range.moveStart('character', textarea.selectionStart - nbLineStart);
                range.moveEnd('character', textarea.selectionEnd - nbLineEnd - (textarea.selectionStart - nbLineStart)  );
                range.select();
```

Which will run on IE 11 platform successfully.

If i am using document.getSelection() method in IE 11 then setEndPoint, moveStart and select methods are not available.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the `window.getSelection()` method to get the selected content

```
function TestSelection() {
  if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var selectionRange = window.getSelection();                                        
    alert("The text content of the selection:\n" + selectionRange.toString());
  } else {
    if (document.selection.type === "None") {
      alert("No content is selected, or the selected content is not available!");
    } else {
      var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
      alert("The text content of the selection:\n" + textRange.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Check this link for your reference:

[Link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgbbkjf.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `window.getSelection` method.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975169(v=vs.85).aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection

```
var range;    
if (document.selection){
    // IE before version 9
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    ...
} else {
    // IE after version 9
    range = window.getSelection();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the function `window.getSelection()`.

A good reference can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection)